# How do I import the frechet_r function from the scipy library?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

When I try to import the function into the library the following error appears:

```
from scipy.stats import frechet_r
```

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'frechet_r' from 'scipy.stats' (C:\Users\melqu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py)
```

I tried calling the function as follows

```
from scipy.stats import frechet_r
```

Is this way of importing correct?

I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling scipy, updating pip, among other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The distributions `frechet_r` and `frechet_l` were renamed in SciPy version 1.6.0.

They were renamed because they were confusing. The `frechet_r` function was an implementation of the Weibull distribution, which was historically known as a Frechet distribution.

[SciPy issue #3258](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3258) explains the rationale for the change.

To fix this, three things were done:

1. `frechet_r` was renamed to [`weibull_min`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weibull_min.html).
2. `frechet_l` was renamed to [`weibull_max`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weibull_max.html).
3. A new function, [`invweibull`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.invweibull.html) was created. This distribution implements the more common meaning of "Frechet distribution."

To replace these, you can use one of these three functions, depending on which behavior you want.